# Browser alert not getting handled results in exception

Tags: groovy, geb

I am trying to handle a unexpected browser alert on Chrome (for leaving required fields blank) and was earlier getting an exception for loading status which was resolved once I changed chrome driver to be 2.24 
and now I am using this code snippet to accept the alert and get past the page

```
public void loginAlert() {
        try{
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException e) {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertText = alert.getText().trim();
            System.out.println("Alert data: "+ alertText);
            alert.dismiss();}
    }
```

which is defined on the page where I expect this alert, also the button that is clicked to invoke this alert is defined on the same page.

Now in my test here is what I have

```
at XXXXPage
classname.WaitForPageLoad()
Button.click()
loginAlert()
```

but here is an exception I get, I have spent a lot of time trying to solve it and finally want to ask for help!

Cannot cast object 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert@7277051' with class 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert' to class 'javafx.scene.control.Alert'
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert@7277051' with class 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert' to class 'javafx.scene.control.Alert'
    at Pages.OperatorLoginPage.loginAlert(OperatorLoginPage.groovy:93)

Also, when I look at the screen shot taken by Geb it appears like this exception occurred even before the alert pop up was displayed since the alert is not showing up at the failed step and it never came up if I monitor the screen while the test runs.

Comment: Have you tried using Geb to handle the alerts? http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/javascript.html#alert

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have imported `javafx.scene.control.Alert` into your class file (I assume by being too quick in the IDE, and just accepting the first recommendation it gave you)

Also, why not use the [Geb mechanism for alert handling](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/javascript.html#alert)?